# How to use Top() method in Apache Pig?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Can someone help me to understand the top() function in pig.Actually I am confused with the parameters for top().
Please explain with one example.

Comment: This is why there is a [manual](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.8.1/piglatin_ref2.html#TOP)

Answer (score 2):

Top() function is used to get Top certain number of tuples which you mention..

Suppose you have some schema let us say
(id,age,name)

```
Dataset:
(1,22,k)
(2,23,j)
(3,22,l)
(4,24,m)
(5,23,n)
(6,24,o)
(7,22,p)
(8,23,q)
(9,24,r)
```

Now simply load this file:

```
A =Load ..
B= Group A by age;
C = Foreach B {
top = TOP(2,0,A)
Generate top;
}
```

Output:

```
({(7,22,p),(3,22,l)})
({(8,23,q),(5,23,n)})
({(9,24,r),(6,24,o)})
```

It will take TOP 2 records of each age.

And

```
TOP(2,0,A) implies TOP(topN,column,relation)
```

So here we said take top 2 records according to 0 column which is id.So two Records with higher(top) id from each age are taken.

Kindly reply me for more query. :-)
Happy Learning.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fetch only top N tuples of a bag. then use `TOP()`.

```
A = LOAD 'file.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (col1:int,col2:int);
file.txt    
(1001,800)
(1001,800)
(1001,800)
(1002,900)
(1003,900)
(1003,900)
(1004,1800)
(1005,1800)

B = GROUP A BY (col1);

(1001,{(1001,800),(1001,800),(1001,800)})
(1002,{(1002,900)})
(1003,{(1003,900),(1003,900)})
(1004,{(1004,1800)})
(1005,{(1005,1800)})

top_data = FOREACH B { top = TOP(1, 1, A); GENERATE FLATTEN(top);};
```

output after `TOP()` , first arg is top N i.e. **1** , second arg is column no. i.e. **1** , third is relation name i.e. **A**.

```
(1001,800)
(1002,900)
(1003,900)
(1004,1800)
(1005,1800)
```